# System.ScheduleBatch not executing on beta-managed package

Tags: managed-package, schedulebatch, beta-managed-package

I have a batch class in which on a specific condition I call system.scheduleBatch().I am passing the instance of the same batch class to  system.scheduleBatch().

```
global class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<ID>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful{
        //some code
    public static ID myMethod()
    {
        MyBatch myBatchObj = new MyBatch ();  
        if(condition1)
        {
            return System.scheduleBatch(myBatchObj ,'MyBatch', 1, 1);
        }
    }   
 }
```

When I execute this class via code it works but when this is executed through managed-beta package Schedule job is visible on UI and it is shown started but does not executes. I also tried on released package the result was same.Its only working upon unmanaged package and code.

Comment: So is MyBatch a class in your managed package and you call yournamespace.MyBatch.myMethod() from outside the package and then it fails?  Also, are you seeing anything in your Apex Jobs list?

Comment: What do the Debug Logs say when you schedule the class? Does your `public static Id myMethod()` need to be global?

Comment: mymethod() is called internally from the finish() method of MyBatch.cls. There is no job seen in ApexJob List.

Comment: The public static method needs not to be global because its called from the same class in which its defined. There is nothing significant in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

There was a Schema.getGlobalDescribe() call in the constructor of MyBatch.cls which was causing the issue. Issue resolved